# In drools When statement is always called of each rule ,Why?

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, rule-engine

I am using drools in my application and I am having many rules like 100s of rules in application. To filter these rules I am using "agenda-group". When I am adding facts in the `ksession` in that when part of all the rules will execute regardless of the agenda-group why it is happening.

I am also focusing the particular agenda

```
kSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("dog").setFocus();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How you confirmed when part of all rules is evaluated ?

Comment: @Abhijit In when part i am calling a function and in that function i am writing a log statement